# Uploading file in an asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, file-upload

I have a problem with the use of UploadFile in asp.net application:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Espace/Sous.master" CodeBehind="Info.aspx.cs" Inherits="Espace.Info1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ChildContent2" runat="server">
<div class="span9">
    <div class="divpere">
        <div class="divfille1">
            <label>Télécharger votre CV (*)</label></div>
        <div class="divfille2">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="cvpath" runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="cvpath" Text="Champ obligatoire" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divpere">
        <div class="divfille1"></div>
        <div class="divfille2">
            <asp:Button Style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #B81C22; margin-left: 73%" runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Modifier mes informations" OnClick="Valider" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            $("input[id*='pick']").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });

        });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

In the code behind :

```
protected void Valider(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.cvpath.HasFile)
    {
    }
 }
```

The problem is that `this.cvpath.HasFile` always  takes *false* even i choose a file.

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How can i fix my code?

Comment: Are you using an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: I tried your code it works fine for me

Comment: Need to see the rest of your aspx page.

Comment: What about your master page.  Can we see that too?

Comment: the master page contains an update panel

Comment: The very first comment I asked you `Are you using an UpdatePanel' and your response `no i don't`.

Comment: put a postback trigger,It'll resolve your problem